# Error with subscript within list of axis labels

Tags: r, list, axis-labels

I have a list of axis labels for various water properties. Some have chemical formulae that need subscript. However, I keep getting an error of: non-numeric argument to binary operator.

This is the code for the subscript.

```
axisLabels <- list('DA' = c('Dissolved Ammonium (NH'[4]*') \n(mg/l)', 'Sampling Site'),
               'DNI' = c('Dissolved Nitrite \n(mg NO'[2]*'/L)', 'Sampling Site'),
               'DNA' = c('Dissolved Nitrate \n(NO'[3]*')', 'Sampling Site'),
               'DS' = c('Dissolved Sulphate \n(mg SO'[4]*'/L)', 'Sampling Site'))
```

This is the Error:

```
Error in "Dissolved Ammonium (NH"[4] * ") \n(mg/l)" : 
non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong here. If you want to use square brackets to indicate subscripts, that can only be done in the context of plotmath expressions:

```r
axisLabels <- list('DA' = expression(Dissolved~Ammonium~(NH[4])~mg/l),
                   'DNI' = expression(Dissolved~Nitrite~(mg~NO[2]/L)),
                   'DNA' = expression(Dissolved~Nitrate~(NO[3])),
                   'DS' = expression(Dissolved~Sulphate~(mg~SO[4]/L)))

par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
lapply(axisLabels, function(x) plot(1:10, rnorm(10), xlab = x))
```

[image]

Or, if you want line breaks, you can use unicode escapes to get your subscript numbers:

```r
axisLabels <- list('DA' = c('Dissolved Ammonium (NH\u2084) \n(mg/l)'),
               'DNI' = c('Dissolved Nitrite \n(mg NO\u2082/L)'),
               'DNA' = c('Dissolved Nitrate \n(NO\u2083)'),
               'DS' = c('Dissolved Sulphate \n(mg SO\u2084/L)'))

par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
lapply(axisLabels, function(x) plot(1:10, rnorm(10), xlab = x))
```

[image]

Comment: How do you do a new line with this syntax??

Comment: @MelanieBaker you can't really. If you are using ggplot rather than base R graphics it is possible to use rich text using the ggtext extension package. Another option if you are using base R graphics is to keep your text as character strings (including line breaks) and use the unicode symbols for subscript 2 and subscript 3 (e.g.  try `"NO\u2083"` or `"NO\u2082"`)

Comment: @MelanieBaker see my update for how this might work in your case

Comment: I am using ggplot. So would those unicodes still work. My graphs are just producing little squares.

Comment: @MelanieBaker yes, it should still work. The little squares indicate that the font you are using does not have these unicode characters. You can try changing the font or you could use `ggtext`